# New close reason "Resolved by professional"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

Sometimes folks ask a question, but then end up calling in a professional to fix the problem. The OP often does not update the question to include what the pro did, or what the problem turned out to be.

In cases like these it would be nice to be able to close the question, since the OP is often not interested in getting an answer.

I propose a new close reason.

"Resolved by Professional"

Comment: My bed was squeaking... called in a professional and now everything is great.

Comment: That or *hit and ran; [answered in comments](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/63440/can-i-glue-the-upper-track-for-mirror-doors)*.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not so sure.

Yes, the OP might not be back or interested in the solution, but other users might be - especially if there is an answer that doesn't involve calling a professional.

Comment: This is true. But sometimes the only person that knows if an answer is actually correct, is the OP.